# Is this asbestos insulation in my attic?

Tags: insulation, asbestos, air-quality, dust

Too scared to go back up here, had found a bunch of spores moving around too when I entered. I have video versions too of these photos, but it looked like giant dust particles were floating around. Should I be concerned?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVyPu.jpg

[image]

Comment: Asbestos needs to be tested to tell.  Asbestos is basically safe to work with, if you wear a mask and are not working with it everyday for years.  If house is younger than 1980s, then the chance for asbestos goes way down.  Asbestos is a danger after years of working with it and not taking basic safety precautions.

Comment: I can't go to imgur from where I am, but my attic always seems to be dusty, I certainly doubt it is asbestos, if I disturb the fiberglass, dust goes everywhere. I always wear a mask when I go into my attic.

Comment: What is your scientific basis for believing that asbestos is dangerous?  Medical data we have is that the stuff is pretty safe, and the only real health problems are from people who were around asbestos dust *occupationally* (8 hours a day 5 days a week for 20 years). They can develop a nasty cancer.  Lowbrow TV is absolutely flooded with lawyers trying to find those victims so they can tap asbestos trust funds and get a 33% contingency fee for filling out a few forms.  Are all those commercials why you think it is dangerous?

Comment: @ Harper,  Just like Roundup.

Comment: [So many questions...](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Basbestos%5D+attic)

Comment: Get it tested!!

Answer (score 7):

That looks like standard cellulose insulation. It's not particularly hazardous.

We can't completely rule out asbestos from here. If the house is in the US and was constructed in the last 40 years, the chance of there being asbestos in that attic is near zero. However for an older house, without testing you should assume any dust could contain lead or asbestos. If you want to be certain you will have to test for it.

Regardless of the presence of anything hazardous, you should be wearing a dust mask when working in a space such as this attic. Going in unmasked means you'll be breathing at least a bunch of dust and dirt in. There's no reason to expose yourself to that crud. I have a half-mask facepiece I use with P99 filters when doing work such as being in the attic or crawlspace.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like vermiculite insulation.  (Little grainy chuncks that sometimes shine on some faces.)  If you look it up you can read on it, but the gist is that not all vermiculite contains asbestos fibers but much of it does.  I think you can have it checked to find out what levels you might have in it.